# How to add memoization in subset sum?

Tags: algorithm, memoization

I am trying to solve subset sum problem with recursive solution, but to make to make it a bit more efficient I am trying to put memoization in it. However the code without memoization gives correct solution but with memoization it doesn't work properly.

```
public int subsetSum(int num[], int idx, int expecedSum, int dp[]) {
    if (expecedSum == 0) {
        return 1;
    }
    else if (idx < 0 || expecedSum < 0) {
        return 0;
    }
    else {
        if (dp[expecedSum] == -1) {
            int x = subsetSum(num, idx - 1, expecedSum, dp);
            int y = subsetSum(num, idx - 1, expecedSum - num[idx], dp);
            dp[expecedSum] = (x == 1 || y == 1) ? 1 : 0;
        }
        return dp[expecedSum];
    }
} 

public static void main(String args[]) {
    Solution s = new Solution();
    int num[] = new int[]{1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7};
    int sum = 0;
    int n = new Scanner(System.in).nextInt();
    int dp[] = new int[n + 1];
    for (int i = 0; i < dp.length; i++) {
        dp[i] = -1;
    }

    dp[0] = 1;
    s.subsetSum(num, num.length - 1, n, dp);

}
```

Can someone help me with why this is not working?

If I enter n = 14 then ideally dp[14] should contains 1 but it doesn't contain 1.

Comment: Could you provide a test case that it fails?

Comment: @kraskevich question updated

Answer (score 0):

The sum is not sufficient to describe the state. The pair (sum, index) is. If you make `dp` an array of arrays of size `(max_sum + 1) x num.length` and apply memoization for a pair `(idx, expectedSum)` in the `subsetSet` method, it works.

Answer (score 0):

It has been years but this may help someone today.
The idea is to take both the state - means once with including current element into the sum and once excluding current element into the sum. and then taking OR(||) for those values and store in the cache.

the code will look something like this -

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>
using namespace std;


bool sumExists(vector<int> & a, int cursum, int n, vector<vector<int>> &dp) {
    if(n==0 && cursum != 0)
        return 0;
    
    if(cursum==0)
        return 1;
        
    if(dp[n][cursum] != -1) {
        return dp[n][cursum];
    }
        
    int newsum = cursum - a[n-1];
    
    bool returnval = false;
    
    if(newsum>=0) {
        dp[n][newsum] = sumExists(a, newsum, n-1, dp);
        dp[n][cursum] = sumExists(a, cursum, n-1, dp);
        returnval = dp[n][newsum] || dp[n][cursum];
    } else {
        dp[n][cursum] = sumExists(a, cursum, n-1, dp);
        returnval = dp[n][cursum];
    }
    
    return returnval;
}

int main() {
    // your code goes here
    vector<int> a{2,0,7,8,10};
    int n = a.size();
    
    int sum = 11;
    
    vector<vector<int>> dp(n+1, vector<int>(sum+1, -1));
    
    for(int i=0;i<=n;++i) {
        dp[i][0]=true;
    }
    for(int i=1;i<=sum;++i) {
        dp[0][i]=false;
    }
    
    if(sumExists(a, sum, n, dp)) {
        cout<<"YES"<<endl;
    } else {
        cout<<"NO"<<endl;
    }
}
```